# Azure DevOps - TestSuite OData API

Tags: azure-devops, odata, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-analytics

I am trying to identify the attribute/property name for Timestamp in the below image. The analytics / odata api in ADO has LastResultOutcome (which is outcome in the below image) but not the Timestamp, I see ActivatedDate, StateChangeDate (see the image below) but not specific Timestamp when the test cases were executed. Which is the exact field to refer to?

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pa86.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZarJo.png)